# When does weak convergence of a sequence imply almost everywhere convergence of Cesaro averages?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, random-variables, weak-convergence, almost-everywhere

Fix $(X,\mu)$ a nonatomic probability space,
$U\colon L^2(X,\mu) \to L^2(X,\mu)$ a unitary operator and $(r_n)$ some fixed sequence such that $U^{r_n}\to V$ in the weak operator topology: $\langle U^{r_n}f,g \rangle \to \langle Vf,g \rangle$ for every $f,g\in L^2(X,\mu)$.

For $f\in L^2(X,\mu)$ denote $f_k:= U^{r_k}f$.

**Is the following true:**

1. *For every $f\in L^2(X,\mu)$, Cesaro averages $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f_k$ converge almost everywhere?*

or, at least,

2. *For any $\varepsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that $ \mu(\{ x\in X : \limsup_n |\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n f_k(x)| > \varepsilon \}) < \varepsilon $ whenever $\|f\|_{L^2}< \delta$?*

For an arbitrary bounded sequence $(f_n)\subset L^2(X,\mu)$ (not necessarily of the form $f_n= U^{r_n}f$) there is only a subsequence whose Cesaro averages converge almost everywhere (by Komlòs and Révész), and Banach-Saks say that weak convergence of $f_n$ implies strong convergence of Cesaro averages again for a subsequence only.

But is there any way to say something about Cesaro averages of the whole sequence, assuming that it is of the form $f_n= U^{r_n}f$ and converges weakly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is nothing to be said about the Cesàro averages of the whole sequence. They can be as bad as the sequence itself.

Indeed, given any weakly convergent sequence $\{f_n\}$, we can consider another sequence $\{g_n\}$ defined as 
$$f_1,f_1, f_2,f_2,f_2,f_2, f_2,f_2,f_2,f_2, f_2,f_2,f_2,f_2, f_2,f_2,f_2,f_2, f_3, \dots $$
where the term $f_n$ appears $2^{n^2}$ times. Note that $\{g_n\}$ also converge weakly.

Due to the super-exponential number of repetition, the Cesàro mean $h_N = N^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^N g_k$ is getting close to $g_N=f_n$ when $N$ is of the form $2^{n^2}$. Thus, the sequence of Cesàro means mimics the potentially bad behavior of the original sequence.

Comment: You are right, of course. It was incorrect formulation of a question I was interested in. [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1516602/does-weak-convergence-in-l2-imply-almost-everywhere-convergence-of-cesaro-ave) is the right one.